iOS cupertino_http error: Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Couldn't resolve native function '_wrapListenerBlock_1a6kixf'
I am trying to run the sample app given with cupertino_http package in iOS. But I am getting below error.
flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:53003/tmg2xds8gus=/
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Couldn't resolve native function '_wrapListenerBlock_1a6kixf' in 'package:cupertino_http/src/native_cupertino_bindings.dart' : No asset with id 'package:cupertino_http/src/native_cupertino_bindings.dart' found. No available native assets. Attempted to fallback to process lookup. dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, _wrapListenerBlock_1a6kixf): symbol not found.

#0 Native._ffi_resolver.#ffiClosure0 (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_patch.dart)
#1 Native._ffi_resolver_function (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_patch.dart:1523:20)
#2 wrapListenerBlock_1a6kixf (package:cupertino_http/src/native_cupertino_bindings.dart)
#3 ObjCBlock_ffiVoid_ffiVoid_NSURLSession_NSURLSessionTask_NSError.listener (package:cupertino_http/src/native_cupertino_bindings.dart:65985:21)
#4 NSURLSessionDataDelegate.URLSession_task_didCompleteWithError. (package:cupertino_http/src/native_cupertino_bindings.dart:66922:14)
#5 ObjCProtocolListenableMethod.implementAsListener (package:objective_c/src/protocol_builder.dart:80:69)
#6 URLSession.delegate (package:cupertino_http/src/cupertino_api.dart:854:10)
#7 new URLSession.sessionWithConfiguration (package:cupertino_http/src/cupertino_api.dart:1070:13)
#8 new CupertinoClient.fromSessionConfiguration (package:cupertino_http/src/cupertino_client.dart:240:32)
#9 main (package:cupertino_http_example/main.dart:23:34)
#10 _runMain. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:301:23)
#11 _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#12 _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)```

